# Python pytz timezone gives just same as UTC time

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

On Linux, I'm trying to get timezone converted time using pytz. But, below code does not return correct 'Asial/Seoul' time.

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz
seoul = pytz.timezone('Asia/Seoul')
curtime = seoul.localize(datetime.now())
```

This is how I tested in Linux. datetime.now() returns UTC time. And, pytz timezone with 'Asia/Seoul' also returns same UTC time.

[image]

I'm looking for answer how to get correct timezone time with pytz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're localising a naïve `datetime`. This means you have a `datetime` with no timezone information; using `localize` on it means you're attaching timezone information where there previously was none. Compare:

```
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 20, 14, 0, 0, 0)
>>> seoul.localize(datetime.now())
datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 20, 14, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Seoul' KST+9:00:00 STD>)
```

It's the same time, once with and once without timezone information.

If you want to get the *current time in Seoul*, you need to create the `datetime` with that timezone:

```
>>> datetime.now(tz=seoul)
datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 20, 21, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Seoul' KST+9:00:00 STD>)
```

Or, you take a timestamp which already has a timezone, and convert it:

```
>>> datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc).astimezone(seoul)
datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 20, 21, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Seoul' KST+9:00:00 STD>)
```

You cannot do a timezone conversion from a naïve timestamp (without timezone), since that inherently has no meaning.

Answer (score -1):

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
seoul = pytz.timezone('Asia/Seoul')
curtime = seoul.localize(datetime.now())
```

This is right.

On your linux, can you show me the output of `date -R`? I assume that your mechine 's tz is utc.

Comment: Yes, my machine's timezone is utc.

Comment: That it why  `seoul.localize(datetimenow())` and `seoul.localize(datetime.utcnow())` is the same.